# Javascript add table in html page

Tags: javascript

I have an html page which includes a table. The following Javascript code a new table to my html page under the table that already exists each time I press the add new button. How can I modify this code so that the user will be able to add only 10 tables?

```
  <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;


        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }

    }

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Wrap in incrementing counter around it just like you do for your table cells, or check the table count before/after the function.

Comment: can you show more code or create any demo on jsfield

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/spetrou/KUfMG/